# Subversion 1.7 vs 1.8 relative (^) symbol oddities

Tags: svn, tags, ls, trunk

I have an external Subversion repo accessed from two separate machines, one machine is using svn v1.7.9 and the other is using v1.8.3.

From v1.7.9 I can use the `svn ls` command with the relative (^) symbol and it works as expected (from the root of the repo)...

```
# svn ls ^/tags
v1-0-0/
v1-1-0/
v1-2-0/
etc
```

From v1.8.3 I try the same command and get the following...

```
# svn ls ^/tags
zsh: no matches found: ^/tags
```

If I run `svn info` from v1.8.3  I can see the `Relative URL: ^/trunk` output as expected (added in v1.8), but it appears I can't go above that level (to the root) using the relative (^) symbol, for example...

```
# svn ls ^/
[returns a list of all files/directories in trunk]
```

This means that almost every command (switch/copy/merge etc) fails when using the relative symbol. Any ideas how I can fix this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, I have not 1.7 SVN in the hands right now (and `zsh` experience at all), but for

```
>svn --version
svn, version 1.8.3 (r1516576)
   compiled Aug 27 2013, 19:43:20 on x86-microsoft-windows
```

and Working Copy, checkouted from the **root of repository**

```
Working Copy Root Path: Z:\TS
...
Relative URL: ^/
```

for pure `^` character in URL I got rather funny results

```
svn ls ^/tags
svn: E155007: 'Z:\tags' is not a working copy
```

(Note "Working Copy Root Path" from svn info output)

but with small trick everything becomes OK

```
svn ls "^/tags"
1.0.0/
1.0.1/
```

I suppose, ^ has special meaning in all shells, you can't use it not protected

Comment: Many thanks! This fixed the issue. I hadn't thought that ZSH might have been the problem!

Comment: The caret is used to escape other shell characters in Windows CMD, this was driving me nuts because every time I tried to `svn copy ^/trunk ^/tags/x.y.z` it would think that I was trying to copy C:\trunk, and tell me it wasn't a working tree.